# Centos 7.5 apache proxy for .net core

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, .net

I am following the instructions to setup apache with .netcore as a proxy server. Here is my vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName localhost.
    ServerAlias *.pointtechsol.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}pts-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}pts-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
service httpd configtest
[Mon Jan 07 17:46:41.520033 2019] [core:warn] [pid 5971] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Jan 07 17:46:41.520137 2019] [core:warn] [pid 5971] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/pts.conf:
Unrecognized header format %
```

I have looked but have been unable to locate the solution. Let me know what other details I can post for help.

Tried this but get same error:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" "expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be here:

```
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
```

The documentation indicates that the expression containing any special characters should be quoted, i.e.:

```
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" "expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}"
```

Comment: I would also check if you have the `mod_headers` module installed.

Comment: httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep header
 headers_module (shared)

Comment: Tried what you said and the error is still there re the quotes

Answer (score 1):

```
expr="%{REQUEST_SCHEME}e"
```